# Duplicate error on xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

```
ld: duplicate symbol _main in /Users/.../i386/main-7E8F26AC10F53546.o and /Users/.../i386/main-B9843B6026D6EFA4.o
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/g++-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

Anyone help with this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you have more than one `main()` function in your code.

Comment: Do i just search through each .h and .m or is there a faster way to search for it?

Comment: yes, you just search for it.  you could install `ack` to search through your code files quickly.

Answer (score 0):

ThiefMaster is right.. search for "main(" in your project and try to clean all targets and build again.

Comment: Do i just search through each .h and .m or is there a faster way to search for it?

Comment: yes press - " command + shift + f " and a dialog will appear you can search there